# Spring cloud config - Remote hung up unexpectedly

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to connect to private gitlab self hosted service with ssh key.
Following is the yaml config

```
spring:
   cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: git@gitlab.devops.mhealth.tech:shivhg/config_src.git
          ignoreLocalSshSettings: true
          host-key: shiva.kumar@mhealth.tech
          strictHostKeyChecking: false
          hostKey: someHostKey
          hostKeyAlgorithm: ssh-rsa
          privateKey: |
```

Also tried .ssh/config update

```
StrictHostKeyChecking no
   PreferredAuthentications publickey
   IdentitiesOnly yes
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/***private
   ServerAliveInterval 60
   ServerAliveCountMax 5
```

Receiving exact same error as #1447 tried the suggestions provided there as well.
Tried in intellij also in iterm console.

Some pointers to fixing this would be helpful, thanks in advance

Comment: Can you attach a full error trace? Also re: "#1447", can you provide a link?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1447

Also the error trace are in following link
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1478
@AndrewRegan

Comment: The Spring code expects your `hostKey` to be Base64-encoded. Is it? It's not clear from your question. Link: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/spring-cloud-config-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/server/ssh/PropertyBasedSshSessionFactory.java#L111

Comment: I am still facing the same issue, no luck!